# How many pages does a book leaf have?

Tags: paper, terminology, book-binding

A co-worker asked a riddle that got me wondering about the anatomy of books and book binding methods.

**The Riddle:**

> A leaf is torn from a paperback novel. The sum of the remaining page numbers is 15,000. What pages were torn out?

According to the answer (and a lot of the internet), it claimed that a leaf: 
 *is a single sheet bound in a book, and a leaf has two pages*.

I thought this assumption was vague and that a leaf can either have two pages or four pages depending on how it is bound. This assumption also changes the answer of the riddle.

**Leaf with two page binding:**

[image: Two page binding]

**Leaf with four page binding:**

[image: Four page binding]

**Are both definitions of a `book leaf` correct? Or is there only one? Is one more commonly assumed than the other?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search revealed that

> Very generally, "leaves" refers to the pages of a book, as in the common phrase, "loose-leaf pages."
>
> A leaf is a single sheet bound in a book, and a leaf has two pages. (Source: [Biblio](https://biblio.co.uk/book_collecting_terminology/leaves-61.html))

A folded grouping of leaves is a "[gathering](https://biblio.co.uk/book_collecting_terminology/%7BGLOBALS.SITE_BASE%7D/book_collecting_terminology/gatherings-71.html)", so the left image under "leaf with 4 pages" in your question is actually a gathering of 4 leaves (8 pages).  The right hand image is a gathering of 2 leaves (4 pages)

Note that if you tear one leaf out of a bound book, as books are more commonly bound in gatherings, often one other leaf will also become loose, and maybe fall out — especially if the leaf torn out is in the centre of a gathering. But that is a separate leaf, not the other half of the same.

Comment: I think your counting is off. The term refers to the front and back of a half sheet as one page, even though numbered it'd be two pages. So the picture would be 1 gathering, 2 leafs, 4 pages, 8 numbered pages.

Comment: @CreationEdge - No.  If you have 8 numbered pages in 1 gathering you have 4 leaves.

Comment: According to [U of Wisconsin](http://creative.uwp.edu/page/sheets-pages), the [English Language Stacke Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/83229) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(paper)), a leaf has two sides and each side is considered one page.

Comment: Which matches what I said @Wimateeka

Comment: I see the confusion I'm having here, it's the phrase "single sheet bound in a book", yet the illustration we're looking at isn't loose-leaf, so a "single sheet" is actually forming _two_ leaves. A better quote for you here is from the [ANSI /NISO/ LBI Library Binding Standard, Z39.78-2000](https://bomi.memberclicks.net/assets/lbc-documents/librarybindingstandard2.pdf): `A single sheet of paper, or one half of a folded sheet of paper. Each side of the leaf is a page. Leaves can be printed or blank.`